# Support / lifetime of OpenJDK 6+7 in Ubuntu 12+14 LTS

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, java, openjdk, support

We have a few systems running OpenJDK 6 on Ubuntu Server 12LTS..we are planning on updating to Ubuntu Server 14LTS with OpenJDK 7.

Unfortunately I cannot find any information about OpenJDK 6 + 7 support under Ubuntu Server (available updates and security patches).

I did find the OEL of Orcale Java SE:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/eol-135779.html

Can I rely on that for OpenJDK under Ubuntu or is there any official-OpenJDK-roadmap out there?

Thanks for you help